# How to listen for changes to the UserDictionary ContentProvider?

Tags: android, textview

I've implemented a spelling checker for ICS/JB. The SpellingCheckerService.Session lets me set the suggestions in the popup menu that appears when you press a misspelled word (underlined in red) but doesn't notify me when the user presses "Add to Dictionary". It just adds it to the Android user dictionary, so my spelling checker will keep reporting that word as a typo.

I could query the user dictionary frequently but that is incredibly inefficient, especially since I'm not even notified if the menu opened.

Is there a way to listen for changes to the UserDictionary, which is a system ContentProvider? Better yet, is there a way to get notified when the user pressed "Add to Dictionary"?

Comment: There wasn't a hook as of 4.0.  This part of the framework isn't really well flushed out, unfortunately.  In addition, most keyboards have their own spell checkers they use instead of this service, as they have their own type detection algorithms and different types of typos most likely based on keyboard layout, language, and input method (voice, tap, swype, etc).

Comment: @GabeSechan I believe you're right. However dtmilano's solution below looks like it will do the trick. It's even better because it will notify my spellchecker of any changes, not just ones that come from the popup menu. BTW my spellchecker is part of a keyboard app (TypeSmart) and the default spellchecker is always stepping on its toes by underlining words in my dictionary. Instead of telling users to disable it, I will tell them to switch to my spellchecker so they can still use the lovely popup menus.

Comment: Good luck with that.  I worked on Swype for 2 years.  As much as I loved the job and what I created, I'm happy not to have to deal with that set of APIs anymore.  BTW, if you want to keep your sanity never look at the code under the hood, it's driven men to drink (or at least caused me to go to a lot of happy hours).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to set a [ContentObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#registerContentObserver%28android.net.Uri,%20boolean,%20android.database.ContentObserver%29) on the [UserDisctionary.CONTENT_URI](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/UserDictionary.Words.html#CONTENT_URI) and get notified of the changes.